# Kotlin - Problems with while()

Tags: error-handling, while-loop, kotlin, reset

I was making a calculator in Kotlin and I'm having trouble solving an issue that I'm having with `while()`.On this particular part of the code, I'm trying to find the first operator in the equation, but I need to exclude the ones that indicate whether a number is negative `-` (or positive `+`, optional), which need to be indicated between parentheses like so: `(-5)`

```
var charay = charArrayOf('+', '-', '*', '/')

var op = 0

var reference = 0

var bol = false

while( bol == false && op != -1){

    println(op)
    println(bol)
    println(bol == false && op != -1)

    op = input.indexOfAny(charay, reference)

    if (!input.get(op - 1).equals('(')){

        bol = true

    }else{

        reference = op + 1
    }

    println(op)
    println(bol)
    println(bol == false && op != -1)
}
```

To test a normal equation I entered the equation `4+4` and the console looks like this:

```
0
false
true
1
true
false
0
false
true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
String index out of range: -2
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at CalculatorKt.CalculateValue(Calculator.kt:67)
    at CalculatorKt.CalculateValue(Calculator.kt:108)
    at CalculatorKt.main(Calculator.kt:119)
```

Like I suspected, for some reason, the variables reset at the end of the `while()`, which is the reason why it never leaves said `while()`. Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error. You're trying to read the character of a string at an index that doesn't exist with this statement:

```
input.get(op - 1)
```

You need to check what `op` is first to make sure it is found. `indexOfAny` returns `-1` if not found in the string. Because we can't see what `charay` is, we can't help you further.

Comment: My bad, still new to this but i hope that I've given you all the information you need now